# Get records with the newest date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the emails of the last person that performed an action over a post. The database structure is a little bit complicated because of several reasons not important for the case.

```
SELECT u.address 
FROM text t 
JOIN post p ON (p.pid=t.pid) 
JOIN node n ON (n.nid=p.nid) 
JOIN user u ON (t.login=u.login) 
WHERE n.nid='123456' 
AND p.created IN (
   SELECT max(p.created) 
   FROM text t 
   JOIN post p ON (p.pid=t.pid) 
   JOIN node n ON (n.nid=p.nid) 
   WHERE n.nid='123456');
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do use the max function or any other way to get the latest date without having to make a subquery (that is almost the same as the main query).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function (aka "analytical" function) to calculate the max date.

Then you can select all rows where the created date equals the max. date.

```
select address
from (
  SELECT u.address,
         p.created,
         max(p.created) over () as max_date
  FROM text t 
    JOIN post p ON (p.pid=t.pid) 
    JOIN node n ON (n.nid=p.nid) 
    JOIN user u ON (t.login=u.login) 
  WHERE n.nid='123456' 
) t
where created = max_date;
```

The `over()` clause is empty as you didn't use a `GROUP BY` in your question. But if you need e.g. the max date *per address* then you could use

```
max(p.created) over (partition by t.adress) as max_date
```

The `partition by` works like a `group by`

You can also extend that query to work for more than one `n.id`. In that you you *have* to include it in the partition:

```
max(p.created) over (partition by n.id, ....) as max_date
```

---

Btw: if `n.id` is a numeric column you should not compare it to a string literal. `'123456'` is a string, `123456` is a number

Comment: How does this compare performance wise with the more classic approach of using a subquery to calculate the max(date)?

Comment: @Rene: in my experience much better because only a single query is executed instead of two queries (the main and the sub-query). But one would need to look at the execution plan to be 100% sure.

Comment: Will give it a try next time the situation presents itself.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly and you explained it very well. Thank you for the advice about the n.nid, but it can contain letters actually. Anyway I'm not authorised to change the database structure...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT address
FROM (
SELECT u.address,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY n.nid ORDER BY p.created DESC) AS rn
  FROM text t  JOIN post p ON (p.pid=t.pid) 
       JOIN node n ON (n.nid=p.nid) 
       JOIN user u ON (t.login=u.login) 
 WHERE n.nid='123456' 
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER` function numbers the rows in descending order of `p.created` with `PARTITION BY n.nid` making separate partitions for row numbers of separate `n.nid`s.

Comment: The `partition by n.id` is not really needed here as only a single one is selected - but it will be necessary when more than one `id` is selected.